# Mock: assert mock_calls with a numpy array as argument raises ValueError and np.testing.assert_array_equal does not work

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, mocking

I have a mocked object that I would like to check its calls using mock_calls, where it is called with **numpy arrays**. But the problem is that it raises ValueError, as shown in the following simple toy example.

```
>>> mocked_model_called_with_np_array = mock.Mock()
>>> mocked_model_called_with_np_array(np.array([1, 2]))
>>> mocked_model_called_with_np_array.mock_calls
[call(array([1, 2]))]
```

Now I set the expected calls:

```
>>> expected_call_with_numpy = [mock.call(np.array([1, 2]))]
```

Now if I check it as shown below, it raises error:

```
>>> assert expected_call_with_numpy == mocked_model_called_with_np_array.mock_calls

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-9806e62badf5> in <module>
----> 1 assert expected_call_with_numpy == mocked_model_called_with_np_array.mock_calls

c:\..\python\python36\lib\unittest\mock.py in __eq__(self, other)
   2053 
   2054         # this order is important for ANY to work!
-> 2055         return (other_args, other_kwargs) == (self_args, self_kwargs)
   2056 
   2057 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**My search on stackoverflow and the found solutions:**

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511931/mocking-numpy-structured-arrays) it is suggested to use `np.testing.assert_array_equal` while you have numpy arrays, but this also does not solve my problems as shown below.

```
>>> np.testing.assert_array_equal(expected_call_with_numpy, mocked_model_called_with_np_array.mock_calls)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-4a0373c94354> in <module>
----> 1 np.testing.assert_array_equal(expected_call_with_numpy, mocked_model_called_with_np_array.mock_calls)

c:\...\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py in assert_array_equal(x, y, err_msg, verbose)
    852     __tracebackhide__ = True  # Hide traceback for py.test
    853     assert_array_compare(operator.__eq__, x, y, err_msg=err_msg,
--> 854                          verbose=verbose, header='Arrays are not equal')
    855 
    856 

c:\...\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py in assert_array_compare(comparison, x, y, err_msg, verbose, header, precision, equal_nan, equal_inf)
    776                                 names=('x', 'y'), precision=precision)
    777             if not cond:
--> 778                 raise AssertionError(msg)
    779     except ValueError:
    780         import traceback

AssertionError: 
Arrays are not equal

(mismatch 100.0%)
 x: array([['', (array([1, 2]),), {}]], dtype=object)
 y: array([['', (array([1, 2]),), {}]], dtype=object)
```

Note that the arrays are the same, but it produces error!

Can anyone comment on how to use mock_calls for a mockec object called with a numpy array and then check if the mock_calls produce the expected calls? e.g., something like below

```
assert expected_call_with_numpy == mocked_model_called_with_np_array.mock_calls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can track the numpy arguments passed to any method of a class, simply by creating a fake (mock) class. For example, if I want to check the numpy calls to method `bar` of an object of class `Foo`, I can do as follows:

```
class MockFoo():
    called_by = []
    def bar(self, *args):
        self.called_by.extend([*args])
```

Now, we have:

```
>>> a = MockFoo()
>>> a.bar(numpy.array([1, 2]))
>>> a.bar(numpy.array([100, 200]))
>>> a.bar(numpy.array([10000, 20000]))
```

Now we can simply check the calls to `foo.bar` as below:

```
>>> a.called_by 
[array([1, 2]), array([100, 200]), array([10000, 20000])]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ran in to the same problem trying to check if mocked calls contained a specific numpy array.
Turns out that the call object is indexable so you can also do stuff like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> mock_object = mock.MagicMock()
>>> mock_object(1, np.array([1, 2, 3]), a=3)
>>> mock_object(10, np.array([10, 20, 30]), b=30)
>>> calls = mock_object.call_args_list
>>> calls
[call(1, array([1, 2, 3]), a=3), call(10, array([10, 20, 30]), b=30)]
>>> calls[0]
call(1, array([1, 2, 3]), a=3)
>>> calls[0][0]
(1, array([1, 2, 3]))
>>> calls[0][1]
{'a': 3}
```

So that instead of asserting that the calls are equal you can just check that the calls were made and that arguments passed were correct individually, ugly but it works:

```
>>> assert mock_object.call_count == 2
>>> assert calls[0][0][0] == 1
>>> np.testing.assert_array_equal(calls[0][0][1], np.array([1, 2, 3]))
>>> assert calls[0][1]['a'] == 3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem comes from numpy overriding `==` operator, returning an array instead of single boolean value.

There is a way around that, though. If you use [callee](https://callee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to check call arguments, you can use callee.general.Matching and provide a lambda to check equality.

Here's how it works with np.allclose

```py
mocked_fn.assert_called_with(
  callee.general.Matching(lambda x: np.allclose(x, my_array))
)
```

Note: I'm not associated with callee library in any way.